# How to refere to 'self' in prototyping

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I´m having an object Task with some observables and non-observables, including an attribute 'ID'.

```
 Task = function(data){
     var self = this;
     self.ID = data.ID || -1;
     //some more attributes...
     return self;
 }
```

Then I´m writing a save-prototype to the object:

```
Task.prototype.save = function () {
    if ( this.ID === -1 ){
        //insert into DB
    }
    else {
        // update DB row with ID = this.ID
    }
}
```

In my viewModel I have an array of 'Task's with a 'selected'-obsevable pointing to the current item in the 'Tasks' array. To check for updates I subscript to the 'selected' with an .isDirty-check:

```
ViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.Tasks = ko.observableArrays();
    // fill self.Tasks-array with 'new Task(data)'
    // ...some json-code to collect tasks from db and map it to 'Tasks'...

    // initiate 'selected' to be first in array
    self.selected = ko.observable(self.Tasks()[0]);    

    self.selected.subscribe(function (task){
        if( task.isDirty() ){
           task.save();
        }
    });
}
```

then from the "jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {…":

```
var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel)
```

Looks clean and simple. Problem is when subscription hits after instancing the viewModel, "this" points to my calling page (an aspx-page in my example).
I have tried changing "this" to "self" with a "var self = this;" declaration, but to no avail (as I also use "self" in my view model and it still refers to the aspx-page.

how can I make the prototype point to it self as an object?

Comment: `this` is set according to how a method/function is called.  You will have to show us where the `task` argument comes from that you show in the subscribe handler.  If `this` is wrong in the `.save()` method, it's because of the value of `task` in `task.save()` so to help you any further, we'd have to know where that comes from.  Right now, there's insufficient information in your question.

Comment: Take a look at [the docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables) on subscribing - particularly the bit around being able to pass a parameter to `.subscribe`, along with your function, that will define what `this` is.  Your code also looks a little odd, in that you seem to be putting a function on a prototype, but then subscribing to that function class as well?  As @jfriend00 says - ideally need a lot more context here.

Answer (score 1):

"this" is kind of magic in JavaScript.

When you init an object using "new" keyword, "this" would be the object that the class creates. This way is commonly used. You should use prototype with this pattern, using "new" keyword.

```
var MyClass = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.myProp = 123;
}
MyClass.prototype = {
    add: function (num) {
        var self = this;
        return self.myProp + num;
    }
}
var test = new MyClass();
console.log(test.add(111)); // => 234
```

When you call a function after the "dot" (.), "this" would be the caller.

```
var myCaller = {
    someFunction : function () {
        console.log(this === myCaller); // => true
    }
}
myCaller.someFunction();
```

If you call a function without a caller, then the default caller would be the root object (window object in browser)

```
var someFunction = function () {
    console.log(this === window); // => true
}
someFunction();
```

Here is an advanced technique.
When you need to override "this", use "call" or "apply" or "bind", of course in case these functions must not be overridden. They take the first parameter as the context "this" when executing the function. For example:

```
var caller = {firstName: "First"};
var someFunction = function () {
    this.lastName = "Last";
    console.log(this === caller);
}
someFunction();                  // ==> false
someFunction.call(caller);       // ==> true
someFunction.apply(caller);      // ==> true
(someFunction.bind(caller))();   // ==> true
new someFunction();              // ==> false
```

Remember that we have 6 ways of calling a function: with a caller, no caller; override caller with "call", "apply", "bind" and the using "new" keyword.

In your case, because you didn't mention how you create viewModel using 1 of 6 ways above. So I assume you are not using "new", you run the function without caller. It means default caller would be window object. Please use "new".